# getting text value from xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

why do i need to use this code to get the text value from the x path

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

with open('restaurants.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write('name \n')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/Restaurants-g1811027-Auckland_North_Island.html')
time.sleep(3)

names = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='biGQs _P fiohW alXOW NwcxK GzNcM ytVPx UTQMg RnEEZ ngXxk']/a")

with open('restaurants.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for name in names:
        file.write(name.text + '\n')
file.close
driver.quit()
```

but when i used my original code it would not allow me to get the text value from the xpath why?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

with open('restaurants.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write('name \n')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/Restaurants-g1811027-Auckland_North_Island.html')
time.sleep(3)

name  = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='biGQs _P fiohW alXOW NwcxK GzNcM ytVPx UTQMg RnEEZ ngXxk']/a")

with open('restaurants.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for i in range(len(name)):
        file.write(name.text +'\n')
file.close
driver.quit
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't the XPath, it's the way you are accessing the `name`/`names` variables.

In the code that isn't working, you are using

```
for i in range(len(name)):
```

but you never reference `i`. It should have been

```
for i in range(len(name)):
    file.write(name[i].text +'\n')
                   ^^^
```

I think your most recent code is much easier to read and follow.

You should spend some time reading up on loops in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) to better understand the difference.